# NODEJS server can not receive request body of XDomainRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, express, server

Simple Nodejs Server like this

```
var express = require('express'), app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9877");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
    /** When Using XMLHttpRequest, set true
     *  XDomainRequest, set false
     */
        next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.text());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("GET METHOD")
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send(200);
});

app.post('/e8', function(req, res){
    console.log("POST METHOD")
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send(200);
});

app.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3001');
});
```

The server is able to receive an XMLHttpRequest request body, but not the body of an XDomainRequest.

What problems could be causing that?

Both clients use text/plain header like `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')` and XDomainRequest can use only text/plain, default header.

EDIT 1: add my client code

```
//XDR
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();

  xdr.onload = function() {
    console.log("ON LOAD")
  }

  xdr.open('POST',url);

  xdr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log("ON PROGRESS")
  };
  xdr.timeout=2000
  xdr.ontimeout = function () {
    console.log("TimeOut")
  };

  xdr.onerror = function () {
    console.log("ON ERROR")
  };

  xdr.send(JSON.stringify(myData));



//XHR
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 /** responseText is not available yet */) {
      const statusCode = xhr.status
      const responseText = xhr.responseText
      //some code
    }
  }

  xhr.open('POST', url, true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  xhr.withCredentials = true 
  xhr.timeout = 2000 
  xhr.ontimeout = function (event) {
   console.log("TIMEOUT")
  }

  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myData))
```

Comment: Please show relevant client code making the request and explain why you're using the deprecated and now removed and IE-specific XDomainRequest instead of CORS.

Comment: @jfriend00 editted. because many clients use IE8 and 9. my project is suppoting them. in my country, so many people use windows and IE8 and 9. it makes me crazy.

Comment: @jfriend00 fixed it `var` but still empty request body

Comment: @jfriend00 until now, i have had no error yet. they are just working properly

Comment: @jfriend00 I think babel, polyfills, plugins made it work. the only one problem is empty request body.